# "failed to execute PosixPath('dot'), make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems" PATH on mac in sage math

Tags: graphviz, sage

I want to use graphviz for graph vizualisation. I would like to use source from graphviz:

```
def display(self, verbose=False):
        '''
        Prints the QMDD as a dot graph.
        '''
        filename = '.tmp.dot'
        self.save_as_dot(filename, verbose)
        s = Source.from_file(filename)
        s.view()
        os.remove(filename)
        # Can't manage to properly remove file .tmp.dot.pdf
```

I always experience this error message :
""failed to execute PosixPath('dot'), make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH.""

I'm using a mac and a sage math in a  jupyter notebook.
I've already `tried to do  pip3 install graphviz and brew install graphviz`. Furthermore I had the path : "/Library/SageMath/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graphviz" to the system path but each  solutions didn't work.

Comment: How is your python script being called? Also, what exactly did you do to add "/Library/SageMath/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graphviz" to the system path?

Comment: From the command line, you could try `sage --pip install graphviz` to make sure that `graphviz` is installed by the same Python that `sage` is using.

Comment: Is the"real" Graphviz package (not the Python library of the same name) installed and in your PATH?  type: dot -V

Comment: Thanks for helping !  I did sage --pip install graphviz  and the package were already installed .
Well , where should I type dot -V ? on the computer terminal the command is not found and in python neither. I think the mistake may come from here (though I did on the terminal type brew install graphviz) . :(
Eventually, to add "/Library/SageMath/local/l..."  I open a terminal, typed sudo -nano /etc/paths and paste the path in  the window that opened. is it the right way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR: first install Graphviz and then install the Python lib.**

The Python library expects the Graphviz binaries to already be installed on your operating system, and these binaries must be able to be executed from the PATH variables in your Python environment.

On Mac - See SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75540940/installing-graphviz-in-macos):

`sudo port install graphviz`

On Linux:

`sudo apt install graphviz`

On Windows (yes, there is an installer but this is easier IMO):

`choco install graphviz # Must be in admin terminal`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
conda install python-graphviz
```

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: What I do is to follow the instruction [here](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_37043191/article/details/122561262) to install graphviz (without root) and run `conda install python-graphviz`. 
It is not wise to install everything under sudo.

Answer (score -1):

For me, what worked was to do:

```
sudo apt install graphviz
```

Looks like python's graphviz module still requires the operating system to have the graphviz libraries installed.