# installing graphviz in macos

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I installed Brew and try to install graphviz using the  command"brew install graphviz"
whereas "Error: graphviz: Failed to download resource "netpbm" Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env svn checkout https://svn.code.sf.net/p/netpbm/code/stable /Users/gj/Library/Caches/Homebrew/netpbm--svn --quiet -r 4482` exited with 1. Here's the output: svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn.code.sf.net/p/netpbm/code/stable' svn: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate has expired"

This error occured and downloading was unsuccessful .

What are the other options to install graphviz i already tried sudo port ?

Answer (score 2):

Using MacPorts:

1. Open the Terminal app on your Mac.
2. Install MacPorts if you haven't already by following the instructions on their website: https://www.macports.org/install.php
3. Once MacPorts is installed, enter the following command to update the package database: `sudo port selfupdate`
4. Then enter the following command to install Graphviz: `sudo port install graphviz`

After installation, you can test if Graphviz is working by running the `dot -V` command in the Terminal, which should output the version of Graphviz installed.

hopes it helps.